# How to use a Firebase Storage URL on Google's and Microsoft's Document Viewer

Tags: firebase, document, viewer

I've read an article that shows how to preview an Office Document (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx) using the following pre-stablished Rest API's provided by both companies.

MS Document Viewer:

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=

GOOGLE Document Viewer:

[https://docs.google.com/gview?url=[DOCUMENT_URL]&embedded=true](https://docs.google.com/gview?url=%5BDOCUMENT_URL%5D&embedded=true)

However, those two options seem to work pretty well with simple URLs, so when I tried to use a sample document which I provide below and which is stored on Firebase Storage, it cannot be previewed nor the URL can be parsed by either Document Viewers in mention.

I would like to ask if anyone knows or has an idea, how to encode or pre-parse the following URL so that my document from Firebase can be properly displayed:

SAMPLE FIREBASE DOCX FILE:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mycloudvip-storage.appspot.com/o/GMbRXZARq1AqDGD0xTZ4%2FnihZvJ4fwXQ2oO40ItWf.docx?alt=media&token=97628604-2ab4-4111-b531-085d545e1a93

Thanks so much and #STAYSAFE

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting to the same experience trying to load the file captured from the storage link.
[image]

Comment: solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68514824/11880166