# How to embed documents from firebase storage into Google/Microsoft document viewer

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-storage

Google Docs and Microsoft office live cannot embed/render doc/pdf/ppt files from firebase storage.
I even set my firebase storage rules to be accessible publicly. I also tried embedding the url using javascript `encodeURIComponent` | `encodeUri` still doesn't resolve my problem.

```
//This is the public url of .ppt that I want to display in my html website:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/work-from-home-app.appspot.com/o/tasks%2Fwqk5vnsYlySImAbukg5Z%2Ftest.pptx?alt=media&token=0eabee36-844f-47de-b643-6fa7d8841dfe
```

I have tried several ways to do it as shown below:

```html
    <!-- This one from google docs doesnt work -->
    <iframe src="//docs.google.com/gview?alt=media&embedded=true&url=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/work-from-home-app.appspot.com/o/tasks%2Fwqk5vnsYlySImAbukg5Z%2Ftest.pptx?alt=media&token=0eabee36-844f-47de-b643-6fa7d8841dfe" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>

    <!-- This one from microsoft doesnt work either -->
    <iframe src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/work-from-home-app.appspot.com/o/tasks%2Fwqk5vnsYlySImAbukg5Z%2Ftest.pptx?alt=media&token=0eabee36-844f-47de-b643-6fa7d8841dfe" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Sadly None of the above works.
But when I tried to embed a .ppt from someone's website it's working fine.

```html
 <!--  This one works!  -->
 <iframe src="//docs.google.com/gview?alt=media&embedded=true&url=http://video.ch9.ms/build/2011/slides/TOOL-532T_Sutter.pptx" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Im guessing that something is wrong with my firebase storage? Or is it not possible at all to render/display document files from firebase to google docs or microsoft api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it!

I ended up using google docs viewer, I cant figure out the one from Microsoft.

The reason it fails to read my document was because the api that I am binding my url is not working for some reason.

```
>This one doesn't work
https://docs.google.com/gview?alt=media&embedded=true&url=my_url

>Works for me
https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=my_url
```

And take note that you need to encode your `url` into an `encodeURIComponent`
if you are using javascript for it to work.